# Biblatex check option with a custom cite command

Tags: biblatex

I have a problem with some customization of my `biblatex`. For some reasons, I want to use a special command to cite normative documents: I would like to make them appear (in both text and bibliography) with a short-name rather than an author name or a number. Plus, I need to use a check option in the printing of the bibliography. Here is my problem, the combination of these two is not working well in my case: the normative text are not appearing in the bibliography.

I assume it is just a problem of definition in the commands, but I did not find the documentation of biblatex how to solve it.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        

\usepackage{hyperref}           

\usepackage[citestyle=alphabetic,
    bibstyle=alphabetic, 
    citetracker=true,   
    mcite=true,             
    backend=biber           
    ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{./biblio.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{standard}{\usedriver{\newblock}{manual}
    \usebibmacro{pageref}
    \finentry}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitetitle}[\mkbibparens]
{\boolfalse{citetracker}
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\ifciteindex
    {\indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}%
    %\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\defbibcheck{mynocite}{
    \ifboolexpr{test{\ifciteseen} or test {\ifkeyword{secondary}}}
    {}
    {\skipentry}
}

\begin{document}        

    Firsts references: \cite{banks92}               
    Eurocode : \parencitetitle{en1998}

    \printbibliography[check=mynocite]

\end{document}
```

with the bib file `biblio.bib`:

```
@STANDARD{en1998,
  shorttitle = {EN 1998},
  title = {EN 1998, Eurocode 8: contruction norms},
  organization = {CEN},
  address = {Brussels, Belgium},
  year = {2005},
}

@book{banks92,
  title={Control and Estimation in Distributed Parameter Systems},
  author={Banks, H.T.},
  isbn={9780898712971},
  lccn={92027712},
  series={Frontiers in Applied Mathematics},
  url={http://books.google.fr/books?id=Gp5usSwk31wC},
  year={1992},
  publisher={Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics}
}
```

Of course, in this example the check option could be removed, but I need it in my bigger cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `\boolfalse{citetracker}` in

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitetitle}[\mkbibparens]
{\boolfalse{citetracker}
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\ifciteindex
    {\indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}%
    %\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

(note that there are two `%` missing after `\boolfalse{citetracker}` and `\boolfalse{pagetracker}` as you can see by the unwanted space after the opening round bracket) you turn off citation tracking for that command. In particular entries that are only cited with `\parencitetitle` give false when tested with `\ifciteseen`.

The solution is to remove the two `\boolfalse`s in the definition of `\parencitetitle`

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitetitle}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
    {\indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

`en1998` will still look a bit stupid in the bibliography, so I suggest you use `shorthand`

```
@STANDARD{en1998,
  shorthand    = {EN 1998},
  shorttitle   = {EN 1998},
  title        = {EN 1998, Eurocode 8: contruction norms},
  organization = {CEN},
  address      = {Brussels, Belgium},
  year         = {2005},
}
```

In fact if you use `shorthand` you can just use a normal `\cite` to get almost the same as `\parencitetitle` (only the brackets are different).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, citetracker=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{standard}{\usedriver{\newblock}{manual}
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \finentry}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitetitle}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
    {\indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\defbibcheck{mynocite}{
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifciteseen} or test {\ifkeyword{secondary}}}
    {}
    {\skipentry}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@STANDARD{en1998,
  shorthand    = {EN 1998},
  shorttitle   = {EN 1998},
  title        = {EN 1998, Eurocode 8: contruction norms},
  organization = {CEN},
  address      = {Brussels, Belgium},
  year         = {2005},
}
@STANDARD{en1999,
  shorthand    = {EN 1999},
  title        = {EN 1999, Eurocode 9: contruction norms},
  organization = {CEN},
  address      = {Brussels, Belgium},
  year         = {2006},
}
@book{banks92,
  title     = {Control and Estimation in Distributed Parameter Systems},
  author    = {Banks, H.T.},
  isbn      = {9780898712971},
  series    = {Frontiers in Applied Mathematics},
  year      = {1992},
  publisher = {Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  First references: \cite{banks92}
  Eurocode : \parencitetitle{en1998} or \cite{en1999}

  \printbibliography[check=mynocite]
\end{document}
```

[image: First references: [Ban92] Eurocode : (EN 1998) or [EN 1999]//References//[Ban92] H.T. Banks. Control and Estimation in Distributed Parameter Systems. Frontiers in Applied Mathematics. Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, 1992. isbn: 9780898712971.//[EN 1998] EN 1998, Eurocode 8: contruction norms. CEN. Brussels, Belgium, 2005.//[EN 1999] EN 1999, Eurocode 9: contruction norms. CEN. Brussels, Belgium, 2006.]